# How to play a shot in a video using JMF?

Tags: java, video, jmf

Here's my problem, I'm using the following java code using JMF for playing video. If I want to play a particular part of a video, lets say a shot (with known starting time and ending time), how to do that(if u know the code please post it here as a "method")
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.media.control.FramePositioningControl;

public class MediaPanel extends JPanel
{
public MediaPanel( URL mediaURL )
{
FramePositioningControl fpc;   

setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); =
Manager.setHint( Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true );

try
  {
     Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer( mediaURL );

     Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
     Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();

     if ( video != null ) 
        add( video, BorderLayout.CENTER ); 

     if ( controls != null ) 
        add( controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH ); 
     mediaPlayer.start();

  } 
  catch ( NoPlayerException noPlayerException )
  {
     System.err.println( "No media player found" );
  } 
  catch ( CannotRealizeException cannotRealizeException )
  {
     System.err.println( "Could not realize media player" );
  } 
  catch ( IOException iOException )
  {
     System.err.println( "Error reading from the source" );
  } 


} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at JMF player APIs  `setMediaTime()` and `setStopTime()`

Comment: Problem solved....... The setMediaTime() works well, but setStopTime() is not responding sometimes.... Thank u jogabonito
......

Comment: But still I can't play different shots by looping the player.. Is there anyother way I can play different non-consecutive shots?

Comment: I didnt understand your question

Comment: Sry even I don't understand what I said.....Imagine if I want to play shots of particular time intervals lets say 1st shot that starts @ 00:02:15 ends @ 00:02:25 and 2nd shot starts @ 00:02:35 ends @ 00:02:40...... how will you play the shots ?

Comment: I would guess setMediaTime(), setStopTime(), start() will work. If you are facing issues with setStopTime(), an easy hack would be setMediaTime(), then sleeping in a thread for 10 seconds, and then on wakeup jump to the next time